# Auto calculate and display timestamp in a specific row and column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a spreadsheet with a formula that works to display the timestamp in the same row, but is there a way to set a column at the same time so I don't have multiple time stamps displaying along that row if I update a different column? I'm not too familiar with code so it may be an easy fix.

```
    function onEdit() { 
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get spreadsheet name 
    var r = s.getActiveCell(); // store active cell name in current spreadsheet 
  var cell1 = 26 // This is the row I want to put values
  if(r.getRow() != cell1) { // Ignores this row (where I put the dates)
    var column = r.getColumn();  // Get column # from active cell
    var time = new Date(); // Get date and time of last mod
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-5:00", "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm"); // Format date and time
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell1,column).setValue(time); // put in time in cell
  };
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present you have

```
var column = r.getColumn();  // Get column # from active cell
```

which means the timestamp gets entered in the column that you edited. If you want to have a single timestamp instead, put

```
var column = 1;  // timestamp goes to Column A every time
```

or some other number instead of 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something really simple.